# How did a website disable Alt-F4 and Alt-Tab?

Tags: malware, google-chrome

I was browsing around on Chrome on a Windows 10 computer, and inadvertently clicked on an ad that appeared under my mouse.

Immediately, the browser went full screen and showed a website saying that they had stolen my data, that I had to call some number, or send some bitcoin or something blah blah blah.

I was a bit surprised that the website actually blocked Alt-Tab so I couldn't change the page, and it also blocked Alt-F4, so I couldn't close the site.

I was able to close the site by logging out through Ctrl-Alt-Del, and to be extra safe, I'm reimaging the computer. However, I'm a bit concerned as to how they were able to pull that off.

The way I see it, there are two explanations to this situation:

**Explanation A:** This was an actual malware attack that got installed by just visiting the malicious website. What I saw was not a website, but the actual malware doing its thing.

I find this to be quite unlikely. The attacker would need a working 0-day Chrome exploit to run arbitrary code, another 0-day Chrome exploit break out of the browser sandbox, and potentially yet another 0-day Windows 10 elevation exploit to install something on my computer. These exploits would be extremely valuable to be used in this petty manner -- there are much more valuable ways to make use of such rare and valuable exploits.

**Explanation B:** More likely, this is simply a website that wants to scare people and then scam them out of their money. I'm not a web developer, but a quick search online doesn't really show ways of disabling Alt-Tab and Alt-F4 from a website inside of Chrome. I wouldn't even understand why a browser would provide such functionality. Is this something that a website can actually do?

I'm a bit puzzled as to how the attacker was able to do this feat. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263935/298043 is part of the explanation

Comment: As Bruno has indicated, probably some JavaScript that blocks certain key combinations.