# Do not open new tab, close tab or close browser window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to block user to open new tab, close tab or browser window for 30 sec when user is on my home page in jquery, javascript. Kindly suggest.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to do that.

Comment: You have no power to prevent user to close its own browser window.

Comment: sounds spammy.  If you legitimate reasons, you can ask the user if he/she really wishes to close the window. read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565304/jquery-prevent-window-closing

Comment: why do you want to do that? Never make any site so user unfriendly.. So avoid that...,

Comment: You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Are you making a porn website?

Answer (score 5):

Answer 1: You can't do that. Browsers quite correctly don't let you. You *can* ask the browser to show a message when the user tries to close the tab/window, [details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565334/157247), but the browser gives the user the option to go ahead and do it anyway.

Answer 2: You ***shouldn't*** do that. You have no right to trap a user on your page — not for *one* second, much less 30 seconds.

Comment: You cannot do that as these are browser defined functionalities.